# PysimpleGUI user input

Tags: python

I need to use the values from the user input as strings, but they come like this ('user input',), I need to take out the ('',).

```
layout = [ [sg.Text("window")], [sg.Text("customer name"), sg.InputText(key="insert name")],
```

So after executing the event( user clicks the button)

```
customer = values["insert name"],

print (customer)
```

When a print the user input I get it `('customer name jhon',)`, so my problem is, how I get the user input without ('',), I only want = `"customer name is jhon"`

Comment: `('user input',)` That looks like a one-element tuple.  Try `costumer[0]`

Comment: It is caused by the last char 'comma' in the statement before you print it.

Answer (score 0):

As @JasonYang pointed out, it is because of the comma on this line:

```
customer = values["insert name"],
```

The comma makes `customer` into a one-element tuple. Remove the comma.